# Problema 1 formulario guarda actualizacion el otro no

Tags: laravel, update

estoy teniendo un problema muy raro, no logro dar con la solución...

Tengo un formulario de categorias y otro de etiquetas ambos crean sus respectivos campos (title y slug)

Ahora bien... para editar... el de etiquetas funciona bien, entonces lo copie y pegue en el de categorías pero para mis sorpresa... allí no funciona.

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function() {
Route::prefix('blog')->group(function() {
    Route::get('tags', [PostTagController::class,'index'])->name('admin.tag');
    Route::get('tags/create', [PostTagController::class,'create'])->name('post-tag-create');
    Route::post('tags/create', [PostTagController::class,'store'])->name('post-tag-store');
    Route::get('tag/{id}/edit', [PostTagController::class,'edit'])->name('post-tag-edit');
    Route::resource('tag',PostTagController::class);
    Route::get('tags/tags-list', [PostTagController::class,'getTags'])->name('post-tag-list');

});
});

Route::prefix('admin')->group(function() {
Route::prefix('blog')->group(function() {
    Route::get('categories', [PostCategoryController::class,'index'])->name('admin.categories');
    Route::get('categories/create', [PostCategoryController::class,'create'])->name('post-category-create');
    Route::post('categories/create', [PostCategoryController::class,'store'])->name('post-category-store');
    Route::get('category/{id}/edit', [PostCategoryController::class,'edit'])->name('post-category-edit');
    Route::resource('postcategory',PostCategoryController::class);
    Route::get('categories/categories-list', [PostCategoryController::class,'getPostCategories'])->name('post-categorie-list');

});
});
```

Mi formulario:

```
<form class="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('postcategory.update', $cat->id) }}">
          @csrf
          @method('PUT')
          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            <div class="row">


      <div class="col-md-4 col-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="first-name-column">Costo de Producto*</label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    id="title"
                    class="form-control"
                    name="title"
                    value="{{$cat->title}}"
                  />
                </div>
             </div>

             <div class="col-md-4 col-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="first-name-column">Costo de Producto*</label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    id="slug"
                    class="form-control"
                    name="slug"
                    value="{{$cat->slug}}"
                  />
                </div>
             </div>
              
              <div class="col-12" align="center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-1">Enviar</button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Cancelar</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
```

Mi controlador:

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $breadcrumbs = [['link' => "/", 'name' => "Home"], ['link' => "javascript:void(0)", 'name' => "Admin"], ['name' => "Equipo"]];

        $cat = PostCategory::findOrFail($id);
        
        return view('blog::category.edit', ['breadcrumbs' => $breadcrumbs, 'cat'=> $cat]);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     * @param Request $request
     * @param int $id
     * @return Renderable
     */
    public function update(Request $request, PostCategory $cat)
    {
        $cat->update($request->all());

        return Redirect::to('admin/blog/categories');
    }
```

dd($request->all());

```
array:4 [▼
  "_token" => "lw15dNsAY89SxCW0ICTK5YDEGIXWDxGlUESpExEE"
  "_method" => "PUT"
  "title" => "esto es una prueba"
  "slug" => "esto-es-una-prueba"
]
```

Las rutas son identicas, y la vista la copie y pegue del de etiquetas... y el controlador copie y pegue el de etiquetas tambien y cambie unicamente el Model...

Repito, el de Etiquetas funciona a la perfección... el de Categorías no funciona, ya hice la limpieza de rutas, vistas y cache.

Ambos tienen en el model:

```
protected $fillable=['title','slug','status'];
```

Answer (score 1):

En el `action` del formulario, le pasas como argumento a la ruta el id de $cat.

```
<form class="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('postcategory.update', $cat->id) }}">
```

En el controlador, intenta cambiar el parámetro del método por un entero (que seria el id) y con el id obtén el modelo y haz el update.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
    $cat = PostCategory::findOrFail($id);
    $cat->update($request->all());
    return Redirect::to('admin/blog/categories');
}
```

Comment: Hola, si eso estaba por hacer porque otro formulario lo tenía de esa manera, pero mi pregunta es... porque en uno funciona y en otro no si son copy paste? es super raro